# Outlook Native application SSO

Tags: microsoft-outlook, azure, azure-activedirectory, single-sign-on

I have on-prem AD running in as federated with Azure and working fine. SSO is working for Web Applications like Edge and Chrome eg. if users are logged in from domain join computer and visit outlook.office.com they are logged in without providing credentials.

However, outlook Application prompts user for the credentials from same domain joined machines.

Any Advise ? What should I look or any configuration relevant, I may be missing

Answer (score 0):

Do you log in Computer using same domain account? In this case, Outlook client will not ask for password as it uses the information from windows account. Otherwise, Outlook would normally prompt for password once when you set up account the first time.

Do you mean Outlook client keeps prompting for credential?

In this case, please refer to this ForumFAQ in TechNet forum to see if it's helpful to you:
[Why does Outlook keep prompting for password](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bcd2d9c2-1a1b-4446-bf32-69fee8cdf11b/why-does-outlook-keep-prompting-for-password?forum=outlook)

Comment: I should have been more clear. It does not keep prompting, as detailed in in FAQ. However, its not using the SSO and prompts for the password. Whereas other other applications like Mail application or Edge, when logging in to office365, automatically use the SSO for current logged in user.

Comment: every time you open Outlook client, you'll need to input password?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it is solved for Outlook 2016 
Enable Modern Authentication for Exchange online

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/enable-or-disable-modern-authentication-in-exchange-online

And 
 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3126599/outlook-prompts-for-password-when-modern-authentication-is-enabled